# Avoid roundoff-issue when aligning real values

Tags: floating-point, fortran

I want to repeatedly increase my variable `time` and make sure it matches all values exact that are a multiple of `align_time`.

Currently I have a function

```
subroutine align(time, incr, align_time)
  real(8) time, incr, align_time

  if (modulo(time+incr,align_time) .lt. modulo(time,align_time)) then
      incr = align_time - modulo(time,align_time)
  end if

  time = time + incr
end subroutine
```

that could be called like

```
time = 0
align_time = 100
do while (time < 10000) 
    incr = cpt_incr(...)
    call align(time, incr, align_time) 
    ...
end do
```

The problem is that due to roundoff errors the program hangs at some point.
Say `align_time` is 0.1 at that point `time` is equal 0.6-eps (with eps the machine epsilon), when it should be 0.6, then `incr` is always set to 0.

I should also mention that `align_time` can change at some point, like `if (time > 1000) align_time = 200`.

Does someone have an idea how to approach the problem in a manner that is save from round-off errors?

[I really do not have any good ideas for tags and headline, please edit if you do. Also, didn't want to add Fortran since the same should apply in C or others]

Edit:
The value of `incr` has to be decreased to achieve the aligning, never increased. `align_time` can be 100 times bigger than the `incr` values but can also be smaller. `incr` is not constant.

Comment: Ideally use an integer as the underlying "clock" then multiply that clock value by an appropriate scaling value to get the actual time. E.g. for 0.1 s intervals use an integer clock where each increment = 100 ms, then multiply by 0.1 to get seconds.

Comment: @PaulR the times without aligning would be e.g. `0.027 0.051 0.069 0.085 0.102 0.122` then the last two values should be adjusted to `0.1 0.120`. I cannot increase `incr` only decrease. (I'll add this to the question).

Comment: It is not possible to make `time` always exactly the nearest multiple of `align_time` because, in general, not all multiples of a value are exactly representable in floating-point. In fact, the values you give as examples, .1 and .12, are not representable in IEEE-754 binary floating-point.

Comment: Have you considered casting your `REAL(8)`s as `INT`s and then comparing the values? Obviously you'd have to multiply by a large-enough number (like 10 or 100, e.g. `itime = INT(time*100d0)`) such that you aren't dropping everything to zero.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it is ok if `time` is an approximation (within roundoff error) to the exact multiple, as long as somehow I can solve the problem that my program gets stuck in some other way

Comment: @KyleKanos that sounds like a good direction, I'll try if I can fix my problem this way

Comment: @Matthias009: We have no way of knowing what will make your program “stuck in some other way” unless you specify the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding `integer(8) itime = 0` and `time_mult = huge(itime)/2/time_end`
in my initialization I changed the subroutine to:

```
subroutine align(time, incr, align_time)
    real(8) time, incr, align_time
    integer(8) iincr, ialign

    iincr = nint(incr*time_mult, 8)
    ialign = nint(align_time*time_mult, 8)
    if (modulo(itime+idt,ialign) .lt. modulo(itime,ialign)) then
        iincr = ialign - modulo(itime,ialign)
    end if

    itime = itime + idt

    time = itime/time_mult
    incr = iincr/time_mult
end subroutine
```

and everything seems to work.

Credits go to @KyleKanos who pointed me in this direction.